# Why GAE dev local connect cloud sql slow?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, pdo, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Google app engine development local server connect cloud SQL by Php PDO very slow 5-7 s. Which i connect MSSQL other server very fast.

## but process on GAE not slow .Is only locel dev.

```
 use Silex\Application;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

     $dsn = getenv('POSTGRES_DSN');
     $user = getenv('POSTGRES_USER');
     $password = getenv('POSTGRES_PASSWORD');

   $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
   $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

Comment: what version of Postgres is it?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6 (google cloud sql)

Comment: How are you connecting to this Postgres in local? 
Using a Cloud SQL proxy or public IP, or else? 

When you are connecting to a Google Cloud SQL with any gcloud command like: "gcloud sql connect mydatabase", GCP will automatically whitelist your ip for incoming connections, even if the IP address is already whitelisted. This process usually takes ~3-5 minutes.
Maybe the way you're connecting to it mimics this behavior.

Comment: I used Cloud SQL proxy.When i call "gcloud sql connect" is very fast on cmd. I connect DB follow https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-sql-postgres @Adrien QUINT

Comment: It seems the cause is the internet connection. What kind of network are you using? Are you using a proxy or a firewall? Have you tried with a local Postgres database? Consider this: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/diagnose-issues#performance